# How to use a python method in swift>

Tags: python, swift

My apps is to do facial recognition attendance taking.
I have the function which is written in python; but I am not sure how to use it in my iPhone apps (Swift). Any idea? thanks.

Comment: You should share code and what you have tried.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: interesting question, but you should share your code at least. People could help you easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an iOS Application using iOS frameworks:

1) CoreML - You can create a new Model for your dataSet or port your existing model to that of an iOS supported type.

2) Vision - For face/image recognition.